# SML Sum of List using option and Pattern matching

Tags: functional-programming, pattern-matching, sml, smlnj, ml

I'm creating sum of list and using `option` in it. When I pass an empty list, I should get `NONE` or else `SOME value`.

I'm able to do that in the following way:

```
fun sum_list xs =
    case xs of
        [] => NONE
      | x => 
        let
            fun slist x =
                case x of
                    [] => 0
                  | x::xs' => x + slist xs'
        in 
            SOME (slist x)
        end
```

But I want to do it in the other way round using pattern matching, in which I want to eval the result of `sum_list` to see whether it is `NONE` or contains some other value.

I have tried in various ways but I cannot get a hang of how to do in that way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*I think what you currently have is very clear and easy to understand.*

If you want to avoid using `slist`, you have to call `sum_list` recursively on the tail of the list, pattern-match on that `option` value and return appropriate results:

```
fun sum_list xs =
    case xs of
       [] => NONE
     | x::xs' => (case (sum_list xs') of
                     NONE => SOME x
                   | SOME y => SOME (x+y))
```